# Java Terminology

Tags: java

I am new to Java and would like to know a bit more.  I have a current problem that I would like an answer to, but I would also like to know what the technique is referred to as so that I can do some further reading.

I currently have something like this:

```
public class BasicActivityExtension {
    public Boolean basicExtensionMethod() { }
    ...
}

public class MyExtension extends BasicActivityExtension {
    public Boolean myExtensionMethod() { }
    ...
}
```

Then in a service method I have (ignore the ( I couldnt work out how to get the < to stay in this):

```
public Class < ? extends BasicActivityExtension> getExtensionByActivity(
                                                     BasicActivity activity,
                                                     ExtensionTypes type)
                                                 throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

**My Question is why does this give an error and what is the name for this technique (when done correctly!)**

```
MyExtension members = (MyExtension) activityService.getExtensionByActivity(activity,
                                        ExtensionTypes.member);
```

The error is 
Cannot cast from Class to MyExtension;

Also if I have an object Class< ? extends BasicActivityExtension> how can I just call the generic methods in BasicActivityExtension without caring what class it is?

Comment: It is not clear on what the relation between `BasicActivityExtension` and `basicExtension` is.  Could you clarify?  Also, class names such as `basicExtension` should be uppercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want

```
<T extends BasicActivityExtension>
public T getExtensionByActivity(BasicActivity activity, ExtensionTypes type) {
....
}
```

When you specify `Class` it has to be a class object,  not an instance of a class.

BTW: I would avoid blindly throwing `Exception` There are better ways of handling checked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called *casting*.

The problem is occurring because you are returning an object of type `Class` from your method `getExtensionByActivity`.  However, you are attempting to cast this to an object of type `MyExtension`.  You would fix this problem by changing the return type of `getExtensionByActivity` from `Class` to `MyExtension`.

Comment: Cheers, that was really useful to see where I was getting it wrong - A Class and an Object are so different but I was getting them mixed up, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Java world, starting Java 1.5 Generics (similar to C++ templates) were introduced in Java. You can read more about Generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

In your given code, it is not clear what is the relationship between `basicExtenstion` and `MyExtenstionActivity`.

In order to call methods in `BasicExtenstionActivity` you have to follow what is called as `Program to an interface` pattern,

Your code should look something like this

```
public Class<T extends BasicExtensionActivity> getBasicExtensionActivity(...) throws Exception.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the extra reading, already used it to work out a bit more and learn how to do Set<T>  Cheers,